# Internationalization in Java Spring with mongodb

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, internationalization

I have a backend in Java Spring with a mongo database, and a collection that stores tours (roadtrips). Since this application is supposed to be used by tourists we want to introduce internationalization. The basic Tour object looks something like this

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c826e272173e100044496b1"),
    "startingDate" : NumberLong(1552160940),
    "start" : {},
    "end" : {},
    "title" : "Dummy tour",
    "duration" : NumberLong(25653),
    "transportationType" : "DRIVING",
    "polylineDecoded" : [ ],
    "waypointList" : [ ],
    "ownerIds" : [ ]
}
```

We would like to add titles based on the user's locale. What is the best way to construct the Tour class? 
Are there best practices for this sort of thing?

**EDIT**: So far this is the most prevalent approach, but I'm afraid it would bloat the tour object in case too many languages are added.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c826e272173e100044496b1"),
    "startingDate" : NumberLong(1552160940),
    "start" : {},
    "end" : {},
    "title" : {
        "en" : "Tour",
        "gr" : "Ξενάγηση"
    },
    "duration" : NumberLong(25653),
    "transportationType" : "DRIVING",
    "polylineDecoded" : [ ],
    "waypointList" : [ ],
    "ownerIds" : [ ]
}
```

Comment: Why not just use a key for the globalizable values, in replacement to the hard-coded value itself? I.e. the only value for `title` would look something like `strings.title`. Then you'd store this in internationalized property resources and retrieve the value given the user's locale. That's pretty much how internationalization works normally.

Comment: @Mena can you give an example in an answer please? I don't understand exactly what you mean.

Comment: You can look e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/index.html) for a quick tutorial on internationalization with Java (probably old, but the general principles should hold). Essentially: you only persist the model-related data in your tour collection, i.e. data on tours, not all translations for common strings. Those are persisted somewhere else as key-values, and when you need to display a value with a given locale, you know the key for it and can retrieve the right value.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link @Mena

Comment: No problems. Have a look at the general principle, but I wouldn't recommend taking everything literally. In my opinion the general idea is that you separate your translations from your business objects, and you translate only in the layer that requires it (typically right at the front-end, but not always), by requesting the translated value given the key (e.g. `tour.title`) and the language (e.g. `el`) or full locale (e.g. `el_GR`), etc. etc.